# ActionController::ParameterMissing in LineItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application, I have Products that a user can add to a Cart. The Products in the Cart are represented by Line Items.

When a user is viewing a Product, they have the option to add the product to their cart as a line item.

I am getting an error when I try to create a new line item instance. I could use some help understanding why I am getting this error and what I could do to fix it.

```
Processing by LineItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3TcxB2vPrhhEqF517yhejZgNSry0uhfjP6bF4Kifd4ofqgDSJH43wtDoNdqTINIkYz1YOx83gAii9Dr5NHgx1g==", "product_id"=>"product"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: line_item):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:72:in `line_item_params'
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Product Catelog (index.html.slim), the button_to is where the line_item is being created

```
h1 My Products

- @products.each do |product|
  .entry
    = image_tag(product.image_url)
    h3
      = product.title
    h4
      = product.description
    .price_line
      span.price
        = number_to_currency(product.price, locale: :fr)
        = button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: product)
```

line_items_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @line_item.save
            format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

    private

      def line_item_params
        params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id, :cart_id)
      end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",       precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this line (last line in `index.html.slim`)

`= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(product_id: :product)`

You'd need to change that to this :

`= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(line_item: {product_id: product})`

Comment: @adamscott Please see the edited answer. I missed the complete error log the first time

Comment: @adamscott Does that fix your issue?

Comment: it did fix my issue, thank you. I am curious though, what was it in my code that made you realize what change needed to be madE?

Comment: to be exact, this : `app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:72:in line_item_params'`

Comment: That line has the `require` method used, which makes sure that if you call the method `line_item_params` it will through an error(your error) if the parameter `line_item` isn't present